# How to create Custom Toast UIView with Button using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to create `toast` message popup with `custom UI` design like below sample image. It should be common class with button actions and it should allow to call from other `ViewControllers` with some message and time interval passing `parameters`. I am looking some initiation codebase with `.XIB`. Please help me to achieve this.

**Expected Toast UI**

[image]

Comment: @Sh_Khan I will post which is I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

It is not tested but it might help you

```
func showToast(message : String) {

      // add label
        let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: self.view.frame.size.height-150, width: 330, height: 35))
        toastLabel.text = message
        toastLabel.alpha = 1.0
        toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true

        //add button 
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: toastLabel.frame.width - 50, y: toastLabel.frame.origin.y + 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            toastLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
            toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. btw is it possible to load .Xib?

Comment: Yes you can load your xib view here directly and add as sub view